# Stop nodejs api from executing multiple instant request from same user

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api

i have an api endpoint, when it is called, it collect user details from the request body and verify that the user balance is is not less than the amount the user want to withdraw, if the user have the amount in his wallet, then after perform other verification the api will subtract the withdrawed amount from the user's balance and send an api request to the payment system that will credit the user's bank account.

At first every thing works well, but if the user sends multiple instant request to the api, the api process all the request and credit the user even if the addition of all the request amount amount is way more than the user's balance

```
<script>
    const data = {
            
            "email": "emailcom",
            "account_number": "938373993",
            "bank_code": "044",
            "amount": 50,
            "naration": "me",
            "currency": "$",
            
        }
    console.log("load")
    const load = () => {
        fetch("https//apiendpoint/", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                "Authorization":"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log('Success:', data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
    }
    for(var i =0; i < 3; i++){
        load()   
    }
</script>
```

if a user has $1 in his/her account and they make a request to this api using that code, it sends instant multiple request to the api and it process the request and credit the user 3times, that us $3 even when the user's balance is only $1

i even used setTimeout to delay, buts its not working at all

please how do i stop the api from process multiple request from same user

Comment: You can't prevent an "advanced" client side user from spamming the requests. The throttling should be made on the server side. As well as the authorization of request to external API.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the `for loop` you added at the end of your code.
Because of this, it is called thrice. Do authorize and write logic at the server side to label the users who were credited recently with the help of a timestamp.

Hope this helps!

Comment: the for loop is the example code he is providing to show how to easily re-produce the issue

what he wants to know is how to protect his backend if an advanced user makes parallel api requests